# Script to resize and rename an image AppleScript

Tags: iphone, applescript

I'm getting sick of constantly have to create images and then have to copy, resize and rename to support both retina and non-retina iphones. Is it possible to have a script that does this automatically if you just drag the image to the script?

The original image will be called: image@2x.png... I would like the script to shrink it by 50 % and remove the "@2x" at the end.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [this site](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-software/perl-image-manipulation.file). I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like it might do what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What I do, in Automator - save as Application

Copy Image, Remove @2x, Shrink

http://new.tinygrab.com/9e397aa2b95f4d2e746e1f5a750eacece89a94dc1b.png

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats amazing. Didn't know that you could use animator :)

Comment: No worries, I have updated it so you can save it in the same directory without having copy on the end of it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an applescript way. Save this code as an application. You can then 1) drop images on it or 2) double-click it and choose a file. It has code to verify that the dropped file has @2x in its name. If so it scales it and if not nothing happens. I see you already have a solution but I wanted to show applescript has the application "Image Events" which can easily scale an image. Good luck.

```
property theSeparator : "@2x"
property scaleFactor : 0.5

on run
    set f to choose file
    processTheFiles({f})
end run

on open theFiles
    processTheFiles(theFiles)
end open

on processTheFiles(theFiles)
    tell application "Image Events" to launch
    repeat with f in theFiles
        set thisFile to f as text
        if thisFile contains theSeparator then
            set savePath to text 1 thru -8 of thisFile & text -4 thru -1 of thisFile
            tell application "Image Events"
                set a to open f
                scale a by factor scaleFactor
                save a in savePath
            end tell
            delay 0.2
        end if
    end repeat
    tell application "Image Events" to quit
end processTheFiles
```

Answer (score 3):

Be warned that all of these approaches (this one included) neglect [pixel-fitting](http://dcurt.is/pixel-fitting), which must be done by hand.

Googling brought up this [Bash script](http://blog.semisecretsoftware.com/streamlining-iphone-asset-conversion-and-resi), which requires installing ImageMagick (via MacPorts) but has the  advantage of sharpening images by a pixel (or more or less if you desire).

Here it is for your convenience (this script takes a series of filenames from the command line):

```
#!/bin/sh  

IMAGES=$@  

RADIUS='1'  
SIGMA='0.0'  
FILTER=Catrom  


for image in $IMAGES  
do  
    /opt/local/bin/convert $image -sharpen ${RADIUS}x${SIGMA} -filter ${FILTER} -resize 50% `basename -s @2x.png $image`.png  
done
```

It is modified from the original version I linked, to not require modifying your `$PATH`

Comment: I no longer believe this is the best approach and [added a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11520505/414415)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that *does* allow for [pixel-fitting](http://dcurt.is/pixel-fitting) and also saves you the additional step of running a script on all of your images; Better results & better workflow!

The prerequisite is that you use Adobe Fireworks to make or export your graphics.

[My iOS Fireworks extension scripts add commands to the Fireworks commands menu to resize your retina graphics or your app icon to the appropriate sizes and open the export dialog for you. Installation instructions are in the README.](https://github.com/iliaskarim/fireworks-iOS-ext)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a script:

I wrote this python script, which you can find on github: [img-asset-creator](https://github.com/Ix76y/img-asset-creator). The script can create image assets for iOS and Android. The only thing you need is having `python3` installed and to make things easier `pip`. The reason I wrote this script is mainly because I wanted to scale multiple images at the same time without having to rely on an internet connection.

For example if you have an image like **pineapple.jpg** and you want to have it for **iOS** in all three sizes with the biggest one to have a **width** of **1200px** you can run the following command:

```
python3 imgasset.py -iOS -w 1200 pineapple.jpg
```

The script currently doesn't support shrinking procentual, but I will add that soon.